# Shinydashboard: Making waiter package wait until plots are fully rendered

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I am currently using the `waiter` package for my initial loading screen. It works great except that is displays my dashboard after the code is processed but ***before*** my plots render.

This behavior is expected due to where the waiter code is placed and how shiny renders plots but I am wondering if there is any way to keep the waiter screen 'alive' until all plots are rendered.

Example below:

```
library (shiny)
library (waiter)
library (shinydashboard)
library (shinycssloaders)

header <- dashboardHeader()
sidebar <-  dashboardSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody(
            use_waiter(include_js = TRUE), # do not include js
            show_waiter_on_load(html = tagList(spin_orbiter(),span("Loading Dash...", style="color:white;")), color = "#3A3F44"), # place at the bottom
            plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot") %>% withSpinner(color="#E4551F")
  )


ui <- ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {

  Sys.sleep(2)
  update_waiter(html = tagList(spin_orbiter(),span("Grabbing a cup of coffee...", style="color:white;")))

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    Sys.sleep(5)
    x    <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = 30 + 1)

    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
         xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
         main = "Histogram of waiting times")

  })

  Sys.sleep(2)
  update_waiter(html = tagList(spin_orbiter(),span("Getting back to work...", style="color:white;")))
  Sys.sleep(2)
  hide_waiter()
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Question is now a bit old but for those whose would need to do it `waiter` proposes a "on render" solution: https://waiter.john-coene.com/#/waiter?id=on-render